# ArrayList content check over entire array

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, return

I'm trying to get this to return a certain number of array entries based on their containing a certain input string.

```
/**
* This method returns a list of all words from
* the dictionary that include the given substring.
*/
public ArrayList<String> wordsContaining(String text)
{
    ArrayList<String> contentCheck = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int index = 0; index < words.size(); index++)
    {
        if(words.contains(text))
        {
            contentCheck.add(words.get(index));
        }
    }
    return contentCheck;
}
```

I don't understand why this keeps returning freaking every value in the array instead of only the entries containing the string bit.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your condition:

```
if(words.contains(text))
```

checks whether the `text` is in the list or not. That would be `true` for *all or none of the elements*.

What you want is:

```
if(words.get(index).contains(text))
```

---

Apart from that, it would be better if you use enhanced for statement:

```
for (String word: words) {
    if(word.contains(text)) {
        contentCheck.add(word);
    }
}
```

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ `contains()`. OP wants to check for substring.

Comment: My eye went for `list`'s `contains` :(

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 issues in your code

The first one is one is that You check in your condition

`if(words.contains(text))` - this check that `text` is in list

and what you probably want is to check that given item of list contains `text`

```
public List<String> wordsContaining(String text)
{
    List<String> contentCheck = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(String word : words) //For each word in words
    {
        if(word.contains(text)) // Check that word contains text
        {
            contentCheck.add(word);
        }
    }
    return contentCheck;
}
```